# What makes hadoop programs run extremely slow?

Tags: java, hadoop

**07/15/16 Update**: It gets in the way again… Could be that I accidentally deleted something with CleanMyMac, but I don't know what I deleted exactly. During the last two days, things were good, so it must be something generated by the OS.

**07/13/16 Update**: After two days of leaving my computer alone, this issue has somehow disappeared, but I still not sure why it happened. I found that I have a dead session in tomcat, don't know if this is related though.

**Original Question**: I'm currently doing some apache nutch development, by the end of the last Friday, it was all good and smooth. But all of a sudden, my programs run extremely slow today, I haven't even touched my working files during the last two days, what could possibly go wrong?

I tried running a single-node hadoop example, WordCount.java, the one provided on [apache hadoop wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount), and the input file contains just two words. And it ran **2~3 minutes** before finishing.

The log file is rather simple, I didn't find anything I can work with.

```
2016-07-11 16:54:37,553 WARN  util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2016-07-11 16:56:38,174 WARN  mapreduce.JobSubmitter - Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
2016-07-11 16:56:38,180 WARN  mapreduce.JobSubmitter - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
2016-07-11 16:56:38,445 WARN  conf.Configuration - file:/tmp/hadoop-Nathaniel_Wu/mapred/staging/Nathaniel_Wu1492571083/.staging/job_local1492571083_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
2016-07-11 16:56:38,449 WARN  conf.Configuration - file:/tmp/hadoop-Nathaniel_Wu/mapred/staging/Nathaniel_Wu1492571083/.staging/job_local1492571083_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
2016-07-11 16:56:38,608 WARN  conf.Configuration - file:/tmp/hadoop-Nathaniel_Wu/mapred/local/localRunner/Nathaniel_Wu/job_local1492571083_0001/job_local1492571083_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
2016-07-11 16:56:38,611 WARN  conf.Configuration - file:/tmp/hadoop-Nathaniel_Wu/mapred/local/localRunner/Nathaniel_Wu/job_local1492571083_0001/job_local1492571083_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
```

After researching for a while, I found that it can run pretty fast if I unplug my network, total run time is about **2~3 seconds**. But the log is pretty much the same, except the timestamps.

```
2016-07-11 17:01:30,536 WARN  util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2016-07-11 17:01:30,928 WARN  mapreduce.JobSubmitter - Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
2016-07-11 17:01:30,932 WARN  mapreduce.JobSubmitter - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
2016-07-11 17:01:31,192 WARN  conf.Configuration - file:/tmp/hadoop-Nathaniel_Wu/mapred/staging/Nathaniel_Wu986778478/.staging/job_local986778478_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
2016-07-11 17:01:31,196 WARN  conf.Configuration - file:/tmp/hadoop-Nathaniel_Wu/mapred/staging/Nathaniel_Wu986778478/.staging/job_local986778478_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
2016-07-11 17:01:31,340 WARN  conf.Configuration - file:/tmp/hadoop-Nathaniel_Wu/mapred/local/localRunner/Nathaniel_Wu/job_local986778478_0001/job_local986778478_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
2016-07-11 17:01:31,342 WARN  conf.Configuration - file:/tmp/hadoop-Nathaniel_Wu/mapred/local/localRunner/Nathaniel_Wu/job_local986778478_0001/job_local986778478_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
```

I guess the problem is concerning the cluster configuration, but the thing is, I didn't configure that at all, all my programs should be single-noded. And I'm running my program in Eclipse, I simply imported the classes needed, and didn't write any configuration file at all.

Now I'm totally lost, I'm new to hadoop, please help, what could cause this issue?

BTW, I'm doing all these on OS X, is this related?

Comment: How did you install Hadoop? Do you have the config files?

Comment: @ILikeTau I built nutch eclipse project using ant, which automatically included hadoop jars in the build path. As for separated hadoop, I installed it using homebrew. If you mean the files in $HADOOP_HOME/conf by "config files", no, I don't, I haven't configured my cluster yet, the programs should be running only on my computer.

Comment: Could you try running it without Eclipse, using `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop`?

Comment: @ILikeTau I tried, it doesn't matter, it can run correctly, just super slow…